The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found. in Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.10.1
I couldn't load my project. and get the error "The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.
It just shows an empty solution explorer but when I manually add files to explorer it complains about non-exiting SDK file which makes no sense because its included in installation.You can see the error msg above but it is in Turkish. It says The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

What’s the output of dotnet --list-sdks?

it does not give any output

That would mean there are no SDKs installed?!

I think you have not installed the .Net SDK while installing visual studio. You can verify it by opening visual studio installer

Click on Modify
Click on Indiviaul Components
Search for .Net SDK

if its not checked then you can install it from here.

